# Supremum of (e^(i z t) - 1)/z

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponentiation

i'm new here, so i'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question:

I know that the following holds true:
$$
   \forall\, t \in \mathbb{R} \; \forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} 
    \qquad : \qquad 
    \left\vert \frac{\exp(\mathbb{i} tx)-1}{x} \right\vert \leq \vert t\vert
$$
but i cant remember the proof...
Does anyone know a quick one?

I actually would need the stronger inequality
$$
   \forall\, t\in\mathbb{R} \; \forall\, z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} 
   \qquad : \qquad
   \left\vert \frac{\exp(\mathbb{i} tz)-1}{z} \right\vert \leq \vert t \vert
$$
but i'm not sure, if this is correct. anyone have an idea?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It isn't correct, for $z = -iy$, the quotient is $\frac{\lvert e^{ty}-1\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert}$, which is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

This is the inequality:

$$
|f(t) - f(0)|= \left|\int_0^t f'(u) du\right|
\le \int_0^t \left|f'(u)\right| du \le
 |t| \sup |f'|
$$

with here, 
$$
f'(t) = ix \exp itx;\\
\sup |f'| = |x|.
$$